# How to mute whole Google Meet meeting

Tags: google-chrome, mac, google-workspace, google-meet

I am looking for a way to mute a Google Meet meeting. I want for a period of time to not listen to anybody that is speaking without disrupting the meeting for the others.

I already tried to right click on Google Meet tab and select 'mute tab' but for some reason, this option is grayed out for Google Meet tabs.

A way to easily mute the whole Google Chrome Application would do also.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Rubén Mac OS sierra

Comment: Strangely there is no speaker icon on the Google Meet tab in chrome, so you can't mute via that trick.  And if you click on the lock to the left of the URL, it gives you the option to mute sound, but it doesn't work for Google Meet.  Seems that Google Meet on Chrome cannot be silenced unless you silence all of chrome, or all of your computer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of February 2023, all Google Workspace editions includes Host Management in Google Meet. When this feature is turned on, meeting hosts can mute all participants at once. For details see [Pin or mute Google Meet participants](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/7501121).

Also, nowadays Chrome include controls that might help to mute the whole meeting, at least for the user at the computer. For details see [Control your music, videos & more](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9692215?hl=en)

---

*Original answer*

The simplest solution is to mute the device by using the device sound controls.

If your device sound controls allow to mute specific applications , mute Chrome.

---

Related:

[Ask Different: How can I control sound from different applications?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28933/how-can-i-control-sound-from-different-applications)

Comment: I don't want to mute the whole device though. Just Meet or Chrome (if the first is not possible)

Comment: @papakias : I added a link to a question about how to mute apps on Mac OS.

Answer (score 10):

Meanwhile you can mute single tabs in Google Chrome. Just tested it with a Google Meet session. All you need to do is right-click on the tab and select to mute the website. Still this will mute ALL running Google Meet sessions, not just the one.

To "mute" a single session you can choose a different Speaker in the settings.

Comment: You are right. This wasn't happening when I posted the question but it works now!

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

You can simply go to that particular tab, right click on it. and mute tab[image]

Comment: Yes right now this is the correct answer. I asked the question back then because this was not available in that particular version of Chrome. Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: Notice there is no "Mute Tab" option, but "Mute Site". With this solution, if there are multiple Google Meet tabs, they are all muted at once.

Answer (score 3):

A very handy solution is to install a Chrome Extension to allow mute individual tabs (instead of all running Google Meets sessions, or changing the output audio device).

Just search for "Mute Tab" in the Chrome Web Store (there are several).

I use this one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mute-tab/blljobffcekcbopmkgfhpcjmbfnelkfg

Comment: This is a pretty old question. I think that after the latest updates Chrome lets you mute Meet tabs now

Comment: I validated every answer before posting my own. All answers remains up-to-date to the current Google Chrome version.